# pointer to structure argv assignment

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, memcpy, argv

I've been trying to assign `argv[x]` to structure pointed to by variable.
I wrote following code and getting Segmentation fault, which I know is a memory violation. I do not understand where I have made a mistake.
Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct somestruct {
   char name[20];
   char surname[20];
   char misc[4056];
} somestruct;


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   somestruct *pvar;
   pvar = malloc(sizeof(somestruct));
   if (pvar==NULL)
      printf("malloc failed with: %s\n", strerror(errno));
   pvar = (somestruct *)  memset(pvar, 0, sizeof(somestruct));

   memcpy((char *) &(pvar->name), argv[1], 20);
   memcpy((char *) &(pvar->surname), argv[2], 20);
   memcpy((char *) &(pvar->misc), argv[3],4056);

   return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct your code, remove `&` in memcpy:

```
   memcpy((char *) (pvar->name), argv[1], 20);
   memcpy((char *) (pvar->surname), argv[2], 20);
   memcpy((char *) (pvar->misc), argv[3],4056);
```

Additionally you are coping to `pvar` from `argv`. the syntax of memccpy is:

```
void *memcpy( void *to, const void *from, size_t count );
```

Where `count` characters from the array `from` to the array `to`.

So

- third argument in memcpy function should be length of `argv[i]` *but not* 20, 20, 4056,
- Also add null `'\0'`.

Do like:

```
   memcpy((char *) (pvar->name), argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
   pvar->name[strlen(argv[1]) + 1] = '\0';
   memcpy((char *) (pvar->surname), argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));
   pvar->surname[strlen(argv[2]) + 1] = '\0';
   memcpy((char *) (pvar->misc), argv[3],strlen(argv[3]));
   pvar->misc[strlen(argv[3]) + 1] = '\0';
```